# Zoom in image inside fluid grid

Tags: html, css, zooming

I am using [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin for fluid grid and would like to add some effects for images on hover, in this the grid has 3 different images with different height: [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/c6h09vpz/1/). Is there some way to keep them responsive and fix heigh change on hover zoom? Please suggest, what has been done wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/">
      <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/n0sl7ucqn/image.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/">
      <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/6r28okkq7/image.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/">
      <img src="http://s17.postimg.org/c12m24flb/image.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
  width: 46.1%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}   

#social_indicator {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 3s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 3s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 3s ease;
  transition:         all 3s ease;
}

.item img:hover {
  width:   105%;
  height:  105%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

}
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` should be on the div - not the image.

Comment: @rblarsen Thank you, I've changed as you said and that fixed the width change, maybe you can suggest how to prevent it from change height, the only problem is I use images with different height in project, so I cant set up fixed heigh for div. Edit jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6h09vpz/1/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `overflow:hidden;` should be on the div, not the image.

I would set the height of the div with jQuery to prevent it from scaling, when the image does:

```
$('.item > a > img').each(function(index, value){
    $(value).parent('a').parent('.item').height( $(value).height() );
});
```

Remember to add the jQuery-library in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tried this idea in fiddle environment, but I think i did't figure out how that really works, can I ask you to have a look to my fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/c6h09vpz/3/

Comment: Oh... you are right. ;) Now I see how it works, actually this approach is good, but is there some way to keep the height of element flexible?

Comment: The height of `.item` will always be the height of its image, when using the jQuery, so if you want the boxes to be smaller, you just make the image smaller.

Comment: Hm, did I understand you write you say the heigh of item depends on image height. I've uploaded 3 images with different height, and noticed some behavior in jquery, it takes the height of first image and applies it to others :( Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6h09vpz/5/

Comment: There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/c6h09vpz/6/ I changed it to take the closest a-tag and not just the first. I have also updated the answer to this.

Comment: Thanks! :) The height now is ok, but did it started to change image height on hover?

Comment: Ah, the jQuery was wrong, I have fixed it and now it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/c6h09vpz/7/

Comment: Now it works super great, thank you a lot rblarsen! I really appreciate the time you have put it!!! Hope that will help others, too. :)